# Geoserver SQL View that uses an existing fuction

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I am attempting to create a Geoserver SQL View layer that uses an existing function in my Postgres/Postgis database.

Starting with the simplest case I have successfully created a layer using the following SQL statement on the Edit SQL View page:

```
SELECT geom FROM map.parcel WHERE pkid = %pkid%
```

Then I create a function in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.gs_parcel (_pkid integer)
RETURNS TABLE (geom public.geometry) AS
$body$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT p.geom FROM map.parcel p WHERE pkid = _pkid;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

And I try to create a SQL View using:

```
SELECT geom FROM map.gs_parcel(%pkid%)
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR: function map.gs_parcel(integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 34
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to expand this simple example to take multiple parameters and add logic, which I can only do using pl/pgsql.

Comment: Sorry, I was suffering from cross-server confusion. I created the Postgres function on my local development server and was tring to access it from GeoServer running on our production server. This part of the problem solved.

Comment: When you say that `This part of the problem solved`, does that mean that you still have a problem?  If so can you edit your question to provide clarification.

Comment: What I meant was I have a lot more work to do and don't know yet if there will be more "problems". If there are I will open new specific questions to address them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably created the SQL View in a `datastore` without access to your `map` schema.
By default, the schema of a new `postgis datastore` is `public`. 
You can change it to `map` or remove it.

Comment: I have a single PostGIS JNDI datastore with "map" as the schema.

Comment: Did you have a valid (i.e integer) default value for %pkid% parameter ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the help. My bad, solution below.